# ObjectAnimator makes imageview disappear

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation, android-view

I'm trying to do a shake animation. It works well when I do it in XML, like this:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <rotate
     android:duration="50"
     android:fromDegrees="-0.02"
     android:pivotX="50%"
     android:pivotY="50%"
     android:repeatCount="30"
     android:repeatMode="reverse"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
     android:toDegrees="0.02" />
 <translate
     android:fromXDelta="-0.02"
     android:toXDelta="0.02"
     android:repeatCount="30"
     android:repeatMode="reverse"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
     android:duration="50" />
</set>
```

But I want to do it using ObjectAnimator, so I'll be able to use AnimatorSet to play this animation at the same time of other animations I've done.

I tried to do it like that:

```
val pvhR = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.ROTATION, -0.05f, 0.05f)
val pvhT = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.TRANSLATION_X, -0.05f, 0.05f)

val rotate = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(imageView, pvhR). apply {
    duration = 50
    repeatCount = 20
    repeatMode = ValueAnimator.REVERSE
}
val translate = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(imageView, pvhT).apply {
    duration = 50
    repeatCount = 20
    repeatMode = ValueAnimator.REVERSE
}
```

But the translate animation makes my imageView disappear. I had problems with rotation animations before (when I tried to do rotation animation, the imageView changed its position, but I fixed it by using `.ofPropertyValuesHolder`, instead of using `.ofFloat`). Probably because I'm using a [custom library that implements a zoomable/pinchable layout](https://github.com/natario1/ZoomLayout).

Now I'm trying to do this translate animation, but it doesn't works even with `.ofPropertyValuesHolderz`. It's working only with XML, but as I said, I can't put it inside an `AnimatorSet()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

        `val set = AnimatorSet()
        val rotation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageViewMain, "rotation", -0.05f, 0.05f).apply {
            duration = 50
            repeatCount = 20
            repeatMode = ValueAnimator.REVERSE
        }
        val translation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageViewMain, "translationX", -0.05f, 0.05f).apply {
            duration = 50
            repeatCount = 20
            repeatMode = ValueAnimator.REVERSE
        }
        set.playTogether(rotation, translation)`

Comment: When answering questions try to explain what the code does and how it solves the problem, instead of just pasting a block of code.